# Iphone Build Release with encryption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encryption

Hello i just want to ask if i build my iphone app for release is it encrypted or not? When the encryption happens? How can i understand if a build is encrypted or not?

```
product -> build for -> archiving

product -> build for -> profiling

product -> build for -> running

product -> build for -> testing
```

are the available...

Comment: What do you mean encrypted? I've never heard of encrypted builds.

Comment: when you download an app from app store it is encrypted. How can i manage it from my xcode or there is no solution? Apple does the encryption ?

Comment: The app is not encrypted, it is compiled. Certain languages like C, Objective-C, C++, Java, etc. have to be compiled into a machine-readable binary file before it can run on a computer. Other languages like Ruby, Javascript, etc. are converted into machine-readable code through an interpreter at run-time.

Comment: There are reverse compilers that exist (Although, Ive never seen one that returns the code just as it was programmed). Although I don't know any for objective-C. Typically, the primary purpose of decompilers is to illegally copy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does the encryption. The tools involved are not available to developers.

Comment: Apps in the App Store are not encrypted. They are digitally signed, however.

Comment: then why there are some anti-piracy codes that check if the file is encrypted?

Comment: @picciano they are encrypted with fairplay.